# ESlint "no-unused-vars" in recursive arrow function

Tags: javascript, format, eslint

At the end of implementing the following generating function (custom binary-search)

```js
const indexOf = (key) => (element, array, start, end) => {
  start = start || 0;
  end = end || array.length;
  const pivot = parseInt(start + (end - start) / 2, 10);
  if (array[pivot][key] === element[key]) return pivot;
  if (end - start <= 1) {
    return array[pivot][key] > element[key] ? pivot - 1 : pivot;
  }
  if (array[pivot][key] < element[key]) {
    return indexOf(key)(element, array, pivot, end);
  }
  return indexOf(key)(element, array, start, pivot);
};
```

ESlint throws a warning " 'indexOf' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars" for the last return statement.

Since it is a recursive function it will be read in the next call (if the pivot element is greater than the current one).

I suspect: ESlint isn't parsing the structure of the conditionals correctly and hence throws the error.

Is my theory correct or am I missing a point here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it'll be fixed once you actually use the function somewhere else

Comment: Well... that was it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out using the generating function in a way like this

```js
export const indexOfByStarted = indexOf("started");
```

removes the Warning.